# Killing vector argument gone awry?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, geodesics

What has gone wrong with this argument?!

The original question

> A space-time such that $$ds^2=-dt^2+t^2dx^2$$
>   has Killing vectors $(0,1),(-\exp(x),\frac{\exp(x)}{t}), (\exp(-x),\frac{\exp(-x)}{t})$.
>
> Given that 
>   $$\dot x^b\frac{\partial}{\partial x^b}(\dot x^a\xi_a)=0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(*)$$
>   where $x^a=(t,x)$, $\dot x^a$ is the tangent vector to a geodesic and $\xi^a$ is a Killing vector, then
>   $$a\exp(x)+b\exp(-x)+c\frac{1}{t}=0$$ where $a,b,c$ are constants.

So I tried directly using $(*)$. What I got are
$$t\dot t\dot x=0\\
\exp(x)(2\dot t\dot x+t\dot x^2)=0\\
\exp(-x)(2\dot t\dot x-t\dot x^2)=0$$
for each of the Killing vectors given.

(Right so far?)

Then multiplying the last 2 equations by $t$ and using the first equation, I get 
$$\exp(x)t^2\dot x^2=0\\
-\exp(-x)t^2\dot x^2=0$$
So any linear combination of the 2 LHS's must vanish, giving 
$$\alpha\exp(x)t^2\dot x^2+\beta\exp(-x)t^2\dot x^2=0$$ for arbitrary constants $\alpha,\beta$.

Either I have gone wrong somewhere, or somehow we must have $$t^2\dot x^2=1+\frac{\gamma}{t}$$

Unfortunately, I can't see why it is so. Any insight? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us denote
\begin{align}
  \xi_1 = (0,1), \qquad \xi_2 = (-e^x, e^x/t), \qquad \xi_3 = (e^{-x}, e^{-x}/t)
\end{align}
Each of these killing vectors leads to a conserved quantity
\begin{align}
  c_1 &= \dot x_\mu\cdot (\xi_1)^\mu = \dot x t^2 \\
  c_2 &= \dot x_\mu\cdot (\xi_2)^\mu = \dot t e^x +\dot x te^x \\
  c_3 &= \dot x_\mu\cdot (\xi_3)^\mu = -\dot t e^{-x} + \dot x t e^{-x}   
\end{align}
From the first conservation equation we obtain
$$
  \dot x t = \frac{c_1}{t}
$$
Plugging this into the second two gives
\begin{align}
  c_2e^{-x} &= \dot t+\frac{c_1}{t} \\
  c_3e^{x} &= -\dot t+\frac{c_1}{t} \\
\end{align}
and adding them together then gives the desired result.

Comment: Thank you, josh. I have double-checked the question and I'm sure I have transcribed it correctly...

Comment: @Jill Yes!  I found my mistake as well; I had, in fact, made an algebraic error.  I edited the response; glad to be of service.